# Can I avoid leaking memory when calling `plan_sequence_path`?

Tags: ros, moveit, motion-planning, memory

**Context:**

I am planning motions for a six-axis robot arm moving a tool along a toolpath. I am working in ROS1 Noetic, calling Pilz Industrial Motion Planner's PTP planner through MoveIt's plan_sequence_path service.

**The problem:**

Every time I perform a motion plan, the memory usage of the `move_group` node increases. This memory is not returned when the plan is complete, and subsequent plans increase the memory usage. This limits the time the robot can run for before running into issues involving swap usage.

Am I missing some function to make the move group release its saved memory, or is this some kind of memory leak?

**What I have tried:**

I have looked through the pilz_industrial_motion_planner code, but failed to find the problem.

I have also tried running the `move_group` node through valgrind, but my other nodes die with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/netshape/internal/ros1/install/lib/ns_hardware/fake_positioner_state_publisher.py", line 24, in <module>
    publisher = FakePositionerStatePublisher()
  File "<node filepath>", line 11, in __init__
    self._positioner = MoveGroupCommander("positioner", ns="/fake")
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/moveit_commander/move_group.py", line 66, in __init__
    self._g = _moveit_move_group_interface.MoveGroupInterface(
RuntimeError: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (5s)
```

Is there some way of suppressing these errors so valgrind can be used?

Comment: Further investigation points to the fcl collision detection algorithm. See https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/3515